# changing common variable value between two java projects not reflecting at run-time

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 3 related java projects in eclipse workspace. I have a class say ClassCommon in third project which is accessible from project 1 and project2 since I imported the necessary packages in them. I am running projects 1 and 2 on the same jvm in local machine.

My problem is this. I have some common variables and methods between project 1 project 2 written in 'ClassCommon' class of third project. Common variables are declared as public static variables. But when I access the common variables and set them a value in project1 process at run time, the project2 process still has the first initialized value only. Change I make to the common variable in one project's process are not reflected in other project's process. I am accessing the variable in both projects as ClassCommon.variable_name only. How these two projects have different copies of the common static variable? When I debugged by stepping, both project1 and project2 process use same class methods but the variables are having their own values though they are public static. Can someone clarify on this issue?

Comment: Is server and client running on same JVM?

Comment: If not running on the same JVM, are they running in the same classloader?

Comment: yes both projects are running on the same machine and same JVM classloader

Comment: If the client, server name confuses you assume two arbitrary projects accessing common static variable of a third project with both projects running on the same machine

Comment: Just to clarify: You are starting both client and server using a single command line call to `java` (or equivalent) to start a program that acts as client and server at the same time. (Also: You should edit your question to include this kind of info; potential answerers shouldn't have to read through comments for it; your last 2 comments contain info important enough to be included in the question itself)

Comment: Just to make sure: In eclipse to run both projects, do you have to click the run button (or use similar means to start server and client) just one time or 2 times (once for server once for client)???? If the answer is "2 times" your programs don't share memory, if the answer is "1 time", try making the fields `volatile`.

Comment: volatile did not help. I have to run two times, one each for a project.

Comment: The 2 projects should be running from 2 JVM processes then (or at least they shouldn't share any memory). Therefore Claas Wilke's answer applies even though you're running your programms on the same physical machine. Maybe there are more effective ways of inter-process communication on the same physical machine. Running server and client on different threads may also be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are addressing is, that you are implementing a client and a server. Most commonly, the client and the server are running on different physical machines, and, thus, in different Java VMs.

Thus, althoug they access the same class and its statical fields, they both have their own runtime instance as they are running in different VMs. If you are trying to modify the same values from your client and your server projects, you have to propagate these changes to the other client/server respectively via your typical client/server communication. Otherwhise, both the client and server will keep their own values for your static fields, which may become different over time.

Comment: Though I said client and server, the client is handling GUI and the Server is a local application server connecting to actual database Server. At deployment both my client and server will be running on the same machine. If that confuses you, assume that the projects have no relationship like client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Generate getter and setter in your common class for all variable and then get and set them via those methods.

hope it will help

Comment: I'm sure this doesn't help. After all it's just setting the value of the field from a different method. Without establishing a client-server communication, no change on the other side will be visible. *Using getters and setters does not change that.*

Comment: I have tried that..Still the values are different. When I debugged by stepping into the common getter setter methods, both client and server processes execute common file and common methods but the values in the common static variable is different in client and server.